# Opening most recently modified file in vim

Tags: shell, files, pipe, date, vi

The following commands work

```
$ ls -1t | head -1
git_sync_log20180924_00.txt

$ vi git_sync_log20180924_00.txt
```

But this does not

```
$ ls -1t | head -1 | vi
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
```

How can I accomplish this (open most recently modified file in vi)?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](/q/128985/47852)

Comment: I set up a shortcut to open in Vim the files edited in the last git commit, in case you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51451515/5419599

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
vi -- "$(ls -t | head -n 1)"
```

(that assumes file names don't contain newline characters).

Or if using `zsh`:

```
vi ./*(om[1])
```

Or:

```
vi ./*(.om[1])
```

To only consider *regular* files.

```
vi ./*(.Dom[1])
```

To also consider *hidden* files (as if using `ls -At`).

Those work regardless of what characters or byte values the file names may contain. For a GNU shell&utilities equivalent of that latter one, you can do:

```
IFS= read -rd '' file < <(
  find . ! -name . -prune -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' | sort -zrn | cut -zf2-) &&
  vi "$file"
```

Answer (score 7):

With your pipeline structure, you could use `xargs` like so:

```
ls -1t | head -1 | xargs vi
```

Comment: That assumes file names don't contain blanks, newline, single quote, double quotes, backslashes and also means that `vi`'s stdin will be either the pipe from `head` or `/dev/null` depending on the `xargs` implementation instead of the tty.

Comment: make that `... | xargs sh -c 'vi </dev/tty "$@"' sh`; vi's input needs to be from a terminal.

Comment: @mosvy, or with GNU `xargs` and a shell with process substitution: `xargs -r0d '\n' -a <(ls -t | head -n 1) vi --`

Answer (score 2):

If you need a more solid solution that doesn’t rely on the flaky output of `ls` you can resort to `stat(1)`. Most implementations have some way to specify a custom output format which can include timestamps to feed to `sort(1)` or an Awk script. Some examples:

- with GNU coreutils:

  ```
  stat -L -c '%Y %n' -- *
  ```
- with BSD coreutils:

  ```
  stat -L -t '%s' -f '%Sm %N' ./*
  ```

Subsequently you can sort and filter the result:

- with coreutils only:

  ```
  stat ... | sort -t ' ' -k 1,1 -n -r | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
  ```

  This requires O(n log n) time to sort the entire input even though you only need the maximum.
- with Awk:

  ```
  stat ... | awk -F ' ' 'NR == 1 || $1 > m { m = $1; n = substr($0, length(m) + 2); } END{ if (NR) print(n); }'
  ```

  This runs in O(n) time because it only compares and updates the maximum.

Comment: How is that less _flaky_ than using `ls`? That still assumes file names don't contain newline characters. You could make it work with the `stat` builtin of `zsh` (which predates both GNU and BSD `stat`) but then `zsh` has builtin support for for sorting file names by modification time, so you don't need `stat` at all there. Or by using `--printf '%Y %n\0'` with GNU `stat` and GNU `sort -zrn`. Also note that the GNU `stat` variant doesn't work for a file called `-`.